# Can I take apart a sillcock?

Tags: plumbing, water, repair, faucet, pipe

Can the body of a sillcock be separated from the body tube?  Without removing the entire sillcock from the wall?

Comment: There are many different kinds.  You may want to post a picture  to get a better answer, unless someone guessed correctly below.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the spigot can't be separated from the tube. The packing nut behind the handle can be removed and then the internal shaft can be removed and you can possibly replace the washer at the valve. In many cases, it's easier to just replace the sillcock.

See picture below from South Side Plumbing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually they can be taken apart.

You want to have the water turned off to that pipe/sillcock before undoing it since it is the inside body/parts that shut off the water.

You need to use two wrenches, one to turn the nuts, and one to hold the outside body from turning.  It will probably twist the pipe if not held.

A picture of the sillcock will help with giving more information on taking it apart.